# jqGrid inline editing: I need do something on cell focus out

Tags: jqgrid, inline-editing

jqGrid inline editing: I need do something on cell focus out. For example: while cell[1][1] focus out, according the value of cell[1][1], I need set the value of cell[1][2] or display a message in a div which is out of jqGrid. I have tried the "oneditfunc", but it doesn't work. Can anyone helps me? Demo is welcome!

Comment: Take a look in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5257794/315935 ) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10667051/315935) which provides examples of usage `dataEvents` with `blur` or `focusout`. Probably it's close to what you need.

Comment: @Oleg Thank you very much!You do me a big favour.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.